# Why no partial function type literal?

Tags: scala, built-in-types

I wonder why there doesn't exist a literal for partial function types. I have to write

```
val pf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 5 => "five"
}
```

where an literal like `:=>` would be shorter:

```
val pf: Int :=> String = {
  case 5 => "five"
}
```

Partial functions are often used and in Scala already some "special" feature, so why no special syntax for it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably in part because you don't need a literal: you can always write your own `:=>` as a type infix operator if you want more concise syntax:

```
scala> type :=>[A, B] = PartialFunction[A, B]
defined type alias $colon$eq$greater

scala> val pf: Int :=> String = { case 5 => "five" }
pf: :=>[Int,String] = <function1>

scala> pf.isDefinedAt(0)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> pf.isDefinedAt(5)
res1: Boolean = true
```

I'm not one of the designers of the Scala language, though, so this is more or less a guess about the "why?". You might get better answers over at [the `scala-debate` list](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/199), which is a more appropriate venue for language design questions.

Comment: +1 I was just going to suggest the type alias trick but didn't know it was possible to take a step further and use the infix form.

Comment: @Vlad, I'll admit that I went through a (brief) type infix operator abuse phase when I first learned about them, and still think it's a pretty nifty little language feature.

Comment: I've asked the same before and the reason that it has not been added to the language (it existed briefly as `~>`) is something to do with how type parameters are inferred l-2-r

Comment: Once paulp added `=>?` to the library, but reversed that because the associativity is not the same as `=>` (a keyword).